# Calcular decimales con consultas Mysql y variables en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql

Cuento con la siguiente base de datos en mysql conectada a mi sistema web:

```
ID  |  PIN  |  r1  |  r2  |  r3  |
 1    BXRDQ    0       1      0 
 2    BXRDQ    1       0      1
 3    BXRDQ    1       0      1
```

La siquiente consulta me da el total de filas registradas y la guardo en una variable llamada $total

```
$cuenta = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT * FROM 
respuestas ");
$total = mysqli_num_rows($cuenta);
```

Posteriormente hago una nueva consulta para sumar y dividir entre la variable $total para calcular un promedio y lo hace pero en decimales.

```
$ambiente = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT (SUM(R1) + SUM(R2) + 
SUM(R3))/'".$total."' AS promedio FROM 
respuestas");
$totalPromedio = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ambiente);
```

Lo que me muestra en total promedio lo hace en decimales pero me gustaría que lo hiciera en enteros, por favor agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Pero que deseas, redondear o solo quitar la parte decimal?

Comment: redondear el total, ya use ROUND() pero no me funcionó

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Pudieras mandar el valor con decimales desde la consulta que te arroja MySQL y que se encuentra en la variable: `$totalPromedio`, pero redondearlo con PHP de este modo:
- Con el uso de `round()` tomas una cantidad y redondeas su valor pero en este caso desde PHP, aunque técnicamente se puede directo desde el gestor

Código

```
echo round($totalPromedio["promedio"]);
```

**Referencia**

- [Función `round` en PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.round.php)

Comment: Una vez más gracias @Aprendiz , lo logré gracias a ti.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque ya está respondida la pregunta añado esta respuesta por si sirve de ayuda a alguien. Hay un sencillo de obtener directamente en `mysql` el valor entero de una división con el operador `DIV`, este operador muestra sólo la parte entera del resultado descartando los decimales.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT,
  R1 INT, R2 INT, R3 INT
);
INSERT INTO test (id,R1, R2,R3) VALUES (1,0,1,0);
INSERT INTO test (id,R1, R2,R3) VALUES (2,1,0,1);
INSERT INTO test (id,R1, R2,R3) VALUES (3,1,0,1);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT (SUM(R1)+SUM(R2)+SUM(R3)) DIV 3 
AS PROMEDIO,
(SUM(R1)+SUM(R2)+SUM(R3)) / 3 
AS NO_REDONDEADO                    
FROM test;

| PROMEDIO | NO_REDONDEADO |
| -------- | ------------- |
| 1        | 1.6667        |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Para redondear decimales en SQL en caso de que quieras redondear hacia arriba usar "CEILING"

```
$ambiente = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT CEILING((SUM(R1) + SUM(R2) + 
SUM(R3))/'".$total."') AS promedio FROM 
respuestas");
$totalPromedio = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ambiente);
```

En caso de que quieras redondear hacia abajo usa "FLOOR":

```
$ambiente = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT FLOOR((SUM(R1) + SUM(R2) + 
SUM(R3))/'".$total."') AS promedio FROM 
respuestas");
$totalPromedio = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ambiente);
```

Comment: No me esta reconociendo ninguno de los dos, amigo @Manuel Panizzo

Answer (score 0):

Si la variable $total cuenta el total de entradas, que en el ejemplo serían 9, la suma de todas da un  número menor y redondear lo convierte a 0.

Si quieres convertir un porcentaje en decimal a entero, algo como: 0.5 => 50%, el porciento se obtiene multiplcando por 100.

```
ROUND(((SUM(R1) + SUM(R2) + SUM(R3))/'".$total."') * 100, 2)
```

Esto lleva algo como el ejemplo anterior de 0.5555 a 55.55%.

Fuera de esto, no veo necesario correr el segundo query para el porcentaje. Puedes hacer una variable en PHP que sume las entradas.

Si sólo quieres los porcentajes, puedes hacer un sólo query que lo haga también.

```
ROUND(((SUM(R1) + SUM(R2) + SUM(R3))/(COUNT(1) * 3)) * 100, 2)
```